# The solution is executed with error 'out of bounds' on the line 25

Tags: c++, clang

Receiving an out of bounds error during compilation, tried alternate approaches still the same. it says error occurred on line 25 which is just a cin statement within bounds. where exactly am I going wrong. Clang, Debugger is generating this error.

```
int main ()
{

  int n;

  cin >> n;


  int work[n];

  for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++)
    {
      cin >> work[j];
    }

    int i = -2, j = -1, k = 0, l = 0;

    int ch = 0, bi = 0, ba = 0;


    while (l < n)
    {
      ch = ch + work[i+3];
      l++;

      bi  = bi + work[j+3];
      l++;

      ba = ba + work[k+3];
      l++;

      i+=3;
      j+=3;
      k+=3;
    }

    if (ch > bi && ch > ba)
    cout << "chest" << endl;

    else if (bi > ch && bi > ba)
    cout << "biceps" << endl;

    else
    cout << "back" << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please choose c or c++ not both, answer may vary depending on the language! VLAs not supported by all languages...

Comment: @CodeTalker this is a wrong source code that contains an «Undefined Behaviour».

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès Ohh, I see. I didn't check the code for logical errors. I ran it for input `5 1 2 3 4 5` and it ran without any errors. Deleting my useless comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++)
    {
      cin >> work[j];
    }
```

Array indexes are from 0 to size-1 (included). Change to:

```
for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
      cin >> work[j];
    }
```

Comment: isn't that the same thing since the index is from 1 to n or from 0 to n-1

Comment: @Atom so you think "123, Main Street" is the same as "124, Main Street"?

Comment: absolutely not, but further in the code my indexes have been used according to  i = 1, its the clang diagnostics which is showing this error

Comment: @atom Sometimes compiler helps not to shoot yourself in the foot.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: Had to add nested if and else to make it work, now it works within bounds

```
 while (l < n)
{
  ch = ch + work[i+3];
  l++;

  if(l<n)
  {
    bi  = bi + work[j+3];
    l++;
  }

  else
  break;

  if(l<n)
  {
    ba = ba + work[k+3];
    l++;
  }

  else
  break;

  i+=3;
  j+=3;
  k+=3;
}
```